# Converting Vector Processing syntax to p5 sketch

Tags: javascript, java, vector, processing, p5.js

I am learning coding and am a novice. I am currently trying to convert a Processing(java) sketch to a p5(javascript) sketch to put on my first website.

I'm having trouble translating the `Vector` and `Array` syntax from the Processing sketch.

This is the `Vector` from the processing Sketch (working):

```
for (int i = pts.size()-1; i >= 0; i --){
    PVector pt = (PVector)pts.get(i);
......
PVector pt2 = (PVector)pts.get(j);
        if (pt.dist(pt2) < 20){
......
```

Here is how I've been trying to translate it in p5 (not working)

```
for (var i = pts.size()-1; i >= 0; i --){

    pt = p5.Vector.pts.get(i);

...........

   var pt2 = (PVector)pts.get(j);

   if (pt.dist(pt2) < 20){
       line(pt.x, pt.y, pt2.x, pt2.y);
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to translate code by going line-by-line and translating the syntax. Instead, you need to take a step back and convert the program into **English** first. Then you take that English and try to implement it in the targed language. That might sound dumb, but that English is called an algorithm.

So, you should have a description of your program like this:

> "Show 10 circles bouncing around the screen. If a circle touches the edge of the screen, it should bounce off by..."

That's just an example, but you get the idea. Then you'd take that and implement it in P5.js.

So instead of saying "how do I convert this array syntax to P5.js", you should be asking yourself "how do arrays work in JavaScript" or even "how do variables work in JavaScript". From there you can read [tutorials](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-variables) to figure out how to implement your algorithm in P5.js.

Then if you get stuck on a specific syntax error, please look in [the JavaScript console](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for any errors you're getting. We can't really help if all you tell us is that it's not working. What error are you getting? Where is your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

All of that being said, I'll try to help with your specific question. Let's take the original line:

```
PVector pt = (PVector)pts.get(i);
```

This line is **declaring** a variable named `pt` and is pointing it at whatever is returned from `pts.get(i)`, which it casts to a `PVector` because Java is statically typed so everything needs a type.

Compare that to what you're trying to do in P5.js:

```
pt = p5.Vector.pts.get(i);
```

First off, where did you declare the `pt` variable? Secondly what is `p5.Vector.pts`? This syntax doesn't make any sense. You need to read up on how variables and arrays work in JavaScript.

Similarly, let's look at this line in your P5.js code:

```
var pt2 = (PVector)pts.get(j);
```

Again, where is `pts` declared? And you never have to cast anything in JavaScript, because it's dynamically typed. Again, you need to go back and read up on how variables in JavaScript work.

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a series of tutorials geared towards Processing developers trying to learn JavaScript, available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help. I was probably too loosely using the word 'translate'. I've actually done a javascript course on Code Academy and have been burying my head in various tutorials (including Shaffman's online vids) for quite a while. More I have a sketch in processing that I'm using as the basis for making a p5 sketch with. 

Anyway, that aside, I'll put the whole code in to answer these questions...

Comment: Oh btw, thanks for the reference to your page. Think I'm familiar with a lot of it, but reading over it now to see if I've missed anything :).